# How to increase volume android

Tags: android, volume

I'm trying to increase/decrease the volume on the nexus player. I made a sample app that works on my phone and other android devices in my house. But not the nexus player. After reading up on it I guess google has blocked this some how. Are there any methods using root to enable this. Here's my current code I use on my phone.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    volumeDown = (Button)findViewById(R.id.volumedown);
    volumeUp= (Button)findViewById(R.id.volumeup);
    audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    currentVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    volumeUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        /* audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                 AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, 0);*/
            audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

        }
    });

    volumeDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("helloworld", "hello" + audioManager.getMode())  ;
            audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please explain where this is from 'After reading up on it I guess google has blocked this some how" and also you do know that there are different streams available from AudioManager right?

Comment: Yeah I tried a couple different streams before I posted. I can't remember exactly where I read that google has blocked changing the volume from the player probably xda developers one developer had fixed it in a Rom he made I believe by messing with audio hal but I'm not sure waiting on a reply